# How to automate route commands

Tags: networking, centos, routing

For some reason everytime I connect to my VM I have to manually launch these two commands for it to connect to the Internet.

```
route add 198.245.49.254 dev eth0
route add default gw 198.245.49.254
```

Is there a way I can automate this so that I don't have to do this manually every time?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Network_Interfaces.html

Comment: the the machines ip address dhcp or static?

Comment: Please give us some more information. What OS is the VM running, CentOS? Do you have root access to it?

Comment: Please post the output of `ip address show` and `ip route show` from within your VM before you enter these commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0** file with the content like this if you use multiple routes:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
10.10.10.0/24 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
172.16.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
```

For the default gateway you need to add this line :

```
GATEWAY=198.245.49.254
```

To the file **/etc/sysconfig/network**

Link: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html